# Can't use camera in the emulator - SD card unavailable

Tags: android, camera, android-emulator

When I am trying to run the build-in camera app from my emulator, I get the message: 'Cannot take pictures without SD card inserted'.

I am using as an *Emulator Nexus 5 API 21 x86*. I checked the AVD Manager and the emulator's SD card is set to work with: .android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd\sdcard.img , so I guess it means it's enabled

I don't understand:
**1.** Why I get this message if it seems like my virtual SD card is set properly

[image: SD settings in the Virtual Device Configuration]
**2.** Why the camera MUST have connection to SD card? In my personal real android device I am using the camera even when I don't have SD card at all. It just store photos to the device's internal storage. 
**3.** in my developed application, as another possible solution, I am calling the camera and providing a file path of **internal storage**, but still I get the same message about the SD card.
My code:

```
int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

public void takePicture(View view){
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = File.createTempFile(
                "blabla",  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                getFilesDir()      /* directory */
        );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't take picture");
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera may save image (or cached image) in SDcard. If you want to test Camera needs SDcard or not (normally not), remove the SDCard option. Otherwise, I think you could try to create new SD card by:

1. Press `Or create new image`
2. Enter 150MB for the new SD card
3. OK and try again.

Comment: Your suggestion to create new SD card worked! thanks. What do you mean by: "...remove the SDCard option." ?

Comment: I means if you want to test whether or not CAMERA needs SDCard, you can remove the SD card and run it again.